# Android: Send message via wechat to specific contact from my application programmatically

Tags: android, wechat

I am developing an demo, in which I want to send message through wechat.
I am using below code to send message to wechat contact.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent1.setType("text/plain");
String title = " this is message ";
intent1.setPackage("com.tencent.mm");
intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,title);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent1);
```

Using this particular code I can send messages by selecting contacts manually.
Can I automate this whole process and send messages from background? `Root` if needed